# ¿Cómo obtener el valor de un input HTML en Twig?

Tags: php, html, twig

Necesito hacer una validación previa antes de agregar datos a un `select`, el tema es que necesito validar el campo `input` y en base a este valor realizar la inserción de los diferentes *inputs*.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="newKeep1" id="area_contingencia" v-on:keyup.enter="addKeep1">
    {%  if  != "" %}
        <select class="areaContingencia_select form-control" name="areaContingencia_select" id="areaContingencia_select" multiple>
            <option class="list-group-item" v-for="(item,index) in lista" @click="eliminarTarea(index)">
                                        ${ item.keep1 }
        </option>
    {%  else %}
        <option value="hola">hola</option>
    {%  endif %}
```